# create view table that calculate total values base on multiple column values

Tags: mysql, view

These are my example table
course  table include

```
course_id     |      course name
1             |       java
2             |       .net
3             |       php
4             |       ruby and rails
```

Indian_student table include

```
course_id     | no.of student
2             |       10
3             |       30
```

Japan_student table include

```
course_id     | no.of student
1             |       50
2             |       30
```

Chinese_student table include

```
course_id     | no.of student
2             |       60
4             |       20
```

I want the output as

```
Course_id |  in_stu   |  ja_stu  |  ch_stu   | total
1         |   0      |     50    |    0       |   50
2         |   10     |     30    |    60      |    100
3         |   30     |     0     |    0       | 30
4         |    0     |     0     |    20      |20
```

But I only get the result

```
Course_id   |   in_stu     |    ja_stu     |    ch_stu     | total
2           |    10        |     30       |    60         |  100
```

my view is

```
create view total_student  as select
i.indian_stu as in_stu,
j.japan_stu as ja_stu,
c.chinese_stu as ch_stu,
main.course_id as course_id,
 (i.indian_stu + j.japan_stu +  c.chinese_stu) as total
from indian_student i, japan_student j,chinese_student c, course c
where i.course_id=main.course_id and j.course_id=main.course_id and c.course_id=main.course_id  group by course_id;
```

can I get any advice please

Comment: you should be left joining across these tables. atm only 2 has students in each table which is why its the only row you get..

Answer (score 0):

You're using the 1990s-vintage method of joining tables together: comma-separated lists of tables. This is inadequate to your task. You need `LEFT JOIN` because the comma syntax is an `INNER JOIN` syntax. `INNER JOIN` omits rows without matches.

(Also, your sample query uses the `c` alias twice; that won't work. It also uses `GROUP BY` but I believe you want `ORDER BY`)

You want this:

```
select i.indian_stu as in_stu,
       j.japan_stu as ja_stu,
       x.chinese_stu as ch_stu,
       main.course_id as course_id,
       (i.indian_stu + j.japan_stu +  c.chinese_stu) as total
  from course c
  left join indian_student i ON c.course_id = i.course_id
  left join japan_student j ON c.course_id = j.course_id
  left join chinese_student x on c.course_id = x.course_id
 order by c.course_id
```

When you develop a view, first get the SELECT statement to work, then use it to create the view. That's easier than continually dropping and recreating the view.

Comment: correction, the comma syntax is a cartesian join: all rows to all rows, not an inner join.

Comment: It becomes an inner join when accompanied by an appropriate `WHERE a.id = b.id` clause, as in this questioner's query. It can't, in MySQL, become a left join.  Oracle has the omega join `(+)` syntax: `WHERE a.id = b.id(+)` but MySQL doesn't.

Comment: So it is still a cartesian join that you then filter with a where clause.